# Mociko Not throwing exception on void methods?

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I tried throwing exception using these two ways but none of it worked;

```
Mockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(inAppNotificationRepository)
  .deleteAll(TestUtil.getNotificationList());

 when(inAppNotificationRepository.deleteAll(TestUtil.getNotificationList()))
        .thenThrow(new RuntimeException());
```

Also none of the other answers are working. Is there any way to throw exception using mockito?

Comment: The provided code is not sufficient to determine the issue. Anyhow I expect `TestUtil.getNotificationList()` some kind of collection that is different (not the same according to `.equals(...)`) from what is called in production code. One solution is to make sure to pass the same objects.

Comment: Or if you dont care about the exact objects you can just use the `any` matcher.